# Rotate UIView to give perspective

Tags: xcode, uiview, rotation, layer, perspective

I want to change the perspective of a `UIView` that is in my `Viewcontroller`. I think that I have to transform this UIView layer, but I don't know how.

I've tried the following code but it is not working

```
UIView *myView = [[self subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
CALayer *layer = myView.layer;
CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -500;
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, 45.0f * M_PI / 180.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;
```

I've also tried with the following code:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    transform.b = -0.1;
    transform.a = 0.9;
    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx,transform);
    // do drawing on the context
}
```

and this too:

```
CALayer *layerA = [[self.view.layer sublayers] objectAtIndex:0];


    layerA.transform = CATransform3DConcat(layerA.transform, CATransform3DMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(45),1.0,0.0,0.0)
```

Neither of them worked. How can I change the perspective of a `UIView`?

In other words, I will put an example. Image this sample code, a rotation Pie [RotationPie sample](http://github.com/wczekalski/CDPieMenu). I would like to change the perpective of it, in the x or z asis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first solution works on my end. It appears like this:

[image]

Can You show your whole class code, if it doesn't work the same on your end?

**EDIT**

Ok, I've reconfigured provided code example, to show how it is possible:

(download here updated code example :http://www.speedyshare.com/dz469/download/Wheel-demo.zip)

And it looks like this:

[image]

I am only applying transformation to base subview. All views that are as subviews to that view, will be transformed as well. If You want corresponding subview to have different transformation - it will be harder, because, then You must take in consideration parent view transformation, to calculate new one - it can get really difficult.

But I've done some simple - multi-view level transformations. For example - to achieve effect, that view scales, moves, and rotates:

- I've applied movement transformation to parentView
- I've applied rotation transformation to parentViews first subview;
- I've applied scale transformation to parentViews first subviews subview.

**EDIT**

Ok, I've reconfigured provided code example, to show how it is possible, in order to leave wheel in transformed position:

(download here updated code example :
http://www.speedyshare.com/5d8Xq/download/Wheel-demo2.zip )

Problem was - in this case, I was adding transformation to wheel itself - and it appears, that Wheel is based on transformations also. Therefore-  when You touched it - it replaced existing transformations and applied it's own (to rotate arrows when user swipes wheel).

So - to leave it in perspective while we interact with it - we need another view layer.

I created a new View (lets call it parent view), and added wheel as a subview to this view.

Then I apply transformation to parent View instead of wheel. And it works !

I Hope it helps and You understand now more about transformations :)

Comment: It is not working in my case. I have several small views that are together in the same view(as a container view). When y try to do the perspective change, the small view separate each other. I also wanted to to the rotation or perspective in another axis.

Comment: download this sample code https://github.com/wczekalski/CDPieMenu imagine that i want to change the perspective to this uiview the CDPieMenu, how can i do?

Comment: I like your answer, i know how to do the animation, but i want to appear with perspective all the time. and when you select a item of the well to continue with the same perspective. I want this wheel with the perspective of 45 degrees for example.In the x asis with perspective and be able to rotate the wheel and continue with the perspective of 45 degree

Comment: in the last answer the wheel is not with perspective. I think that the perspective have to be done in the method - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect in the CDCircleOverlayView class or CDCircle or CDCircleOverlayView.What do you think?

Comment: It is with perspective. Perspective can be changed by changing m34 parameter and transformation angle. (Check far left arrow with far right arrow.. One looks bigger than other - therefore it is perspective. ) Also - set background color to parent subview, to see that it actually is in perspective.

Comment: You have experience with this sample, is it easy to avoid to rotate to one direction?I mean, allow to rotate this wheel only in one direction

Comment: Glad I could help :) You should look into - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event - store angleInRadians value and compare it with previously saved before setting transformation, to find out whether it is going in opposite direction or in right direction (then accordingly allow or don't allow to transform).

Comment: what do you mean to compare the currentTransformAngle and the angleInRadians. angleInRadians could be positive or negative in both directions

Comment: CGFloat angleInRadians = atan2f(currentTouchPoint.y - center.y, currentTouchPoint.x - center.x) - atan2f(previousTouchPoint.y - center.y, previousTouchPoint.x - center.x);
    How can i comprare this two values to know the previous direction (first & second)
    CGFloat first = atan2f(currentTouchPoint.y - center.y, currentTouchPoint.x - center.x); 
    
     CGFloat second =atan2f(previousTouchPoint.y - center.y, previousTouchPoint.x - center.x);    
    currentTransformAngle = atan2f(view.transform.b, view.transform.a);

Comment: When I did this: 
NSLog(@"%f",angleInRadians);  It looked that it was always negative in one direction.
But after further testing, it looks like my proposal will not work. I am sorry.

Comment: i think that the method where i can check it is the touchesMoved, but all the values that i get when i try in both direction always are different.any suggestion?

Comment: This is not my strong side. I would suggest creating a new question (to attract more people), with the same project link, example code from touchesModed and question - how to allow transformations only in one direction. Good luck!